# Symfony2: List public cities by country

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have two tables, one containing cities and one containing countries. Those are bi-directional linked as discussed here: [Symfony2: List cities by country](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9701548/symfony2-list-cities-by-country)

Every city has a flag called 'public'. What I need to do now is, to list only countries that have cities, that are marked as 'public' and this public cities to every country.
If a country has no public cities, it should not be listed.

How to handle this problem best?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should override the `$country->getCities($onlyPublic = true)` method and place that logic in there.

Comment: How would that work, if the value of the comparison (in this case 'public') is dynamic? Can I give that to the $country->getCities() function?

Comment: Well, you can have that as a receiving parameter, like `getCities($onlyPublic = true)`.